# How do I scan a file in C using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am using the code

```
while(fscanf(input, "%49[^@ ]@%49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s", sender, trash, receiver, trash) != EOF){
   printf("%s " "%s\n", sender, reciever);
}
```

to try to read and print every line from a file
however when I run this code it gets stuck in an endless loop printing the first line of the file over and over again. How can I move the scanner down to the next line after it has executed this code. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you list some lines from the input file? Maybe some argument does not match. It also could be, that `fscanf` does not work correctly, if a argument is repeated (like `trash` in your case).

Comment: You may be missing end-of-line character in format string. `sscanf` is not line-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include < stdio.h >

FILE *fr;

main()
{
    int n;
    char line[80];

    fr = fopen ("test.txt", "r");  /* open the file for reading */

    while(fgets(line, 80, fr) != NULL)
    {
    /* get a line, up to 80 chars from fr.  done if NULL */
    sscanf  ( line );
    }
    fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
}
```

The basic way to do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf()` returns number of conversions made. `EOF` is only returned when the *very first* conversion has failed. The proper way would be:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "...", &v1, &v2, ...) == <number_of_variables_read>) {
    ...
}

if (ferror(fp)) ...
```

Comment: `man fscanf`: "The value EOF is returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-of-file occurs. "

Answer (score 0):

```
  do {
        fscanf(input, "%49[^@ ]@%49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s", sender, trash, receiver, trash);
        printf("%s " "%s\n", sender, reciever);
     } while(!feof(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check return value from `fscanf`. This function returns number of succesful conversions, which may be less than number of conversions specified in format string.

In your case, it may mean that no conversions may have been performed in second call to `fscanf`, becaude of malformed data in file etc. As no data was read, file handle has not advanced, so end-of-file hasn't been reached, which in turn explains why loop does not terminate. As no data was read, previous values are printed in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare against EOF, compare against the expected number of parsed fields.

```
while(3 == fscanf(input, " %49[^@ ]@%*49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s", sender, receiver, trash)){
   printf("%s " "%s\n", sender, receiver);
}
```

Some minor changes

Suspect you may want to skip over any leading whitespace, so begin format with `" "`.  ( I am sure this is contributing to your end-less loop.  First scanning leave the `\n` in the input queue.  2nd scan won't put `\n` into `sender` and `fscanf()` returns 0, which is not EOF.  Vicious cycle repeats.)

No need to *save* your first scanning of trash field with `"%49s".  Use "*" to scan and not save.

Scan the second trash field *and* save to add to the scan count.  This helps validate the incoming data is formatted as expected.  An alternate pedantic check could be `" %49[^@ ]@%*49s -> %49[^@ ]@%*49s%[\n]`.

BTW, recommend using `fgets()` to get the line and use `sscanf()` to tear apart.  Easier to handle I/O and parsing errors.