# Why is my fscanf() not reading the middle variable?

Tags: c, scanf

This is probably a very simple fix, but I'm not seeing it.
Let's say that my file looks like this:

```
Katze cat 1
Hund dog 1
Fisch fish 3
```

I use this to read it:

```
char a[1000], b[1000];
unsigned box;
while(fscanf(in, "%s %s %u", a, b, &box) == 3) {
```

and then, to check, I put this immediately afterward:

```
printf("\njust read: '%s' '%s' '%u'", a, b, box);
```

The output I get is this:

```
just read: 'Katze' '' '1'
just read: 'Hund' '' '1'
just read: 'Fisch' '' '3'
```

I can't figure out where the second string went.

---

To satisfy requests for more code:

```
if(argc==3 && (!strcmp(argv[1], "test"))){

        //try to open the 3rd argument, to read.    
        if((in = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
            printf("\n%s: cannot open '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
            exit(1);
        }

            //read data from .fee file.
            while(fscanf(in, "%s %s %u", a, b, &box) == 3) {

                printf("\njust read: '%s' '%s' '%u'", a, b, box);
```

---

UPDATE:
I fixed it, but I still don't understand why the error manifested itself the way it did.  The problem was that I had, in fact, defined 'box' as a char, not an unsigned, as I had claimed above.  When I changed this, the code works perfectly.

Any ideas why that would have caused it to ignore the second string yet still pick up the integer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scan a file in C using fscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323113/how-do-i-scan-a-file-in-c-using-fscanf)

Comment: Show the definition of `a` and `b`'

Comment: a and b are just character arrays.

Comment: Code looks good - maybe some _other_ code is UB? or what is  posted is not what you compiled.

Comment: I did a little test and it works for me.

Comment: @Korgan Rivera  Need to post your true code including `#include`, else it will be more difficult to guess the problem, as what is here is OK.

Comment: Standard nag: *always* post a *complete* example if that example will be less than 50 lines of code. Consider posting complete examples even if the example will exceed 40 lines (but do some work to make the complete example a reasonable size).

Comment: @MichaelBurr The reason I haven't posted the entire code is that it's about 200 lines long.  Besides that, this is the first use of any of these variables, which is why it's confusing me.

Comment: Could it be a problem that one of the `%s` formats is reading the newline immediately after `%u` and exiting with an empty string?

Comment: @Drew McGowen No, not possible.

Comment: The improved code still does not show `a`, `b` and `box` in the _same_ sample.  Certainly, it could be that `b` occurs in 2 places and the usage here is incorrect.  As @Michael Burr said, post a complete self contained code block - if possible.

Comment: "Any ideas why that would have caused it to ignore the second string yet still pick up the integer?"  @Brian Walker answer explains well why using `"%u"` would affect more than `box`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had "box" defined as a char (1 byte) the fscanf is still going to write 4 bytes to the address (because you have %u in the fscanf format). The mismatch in the data type versus the fscanf format type causes a buffer overflow.

When the fscanf runs it will write data into the "a" buffer, then data into the "b" buffer, and then data into the memory for "box". Since "box" has 1 byte reserved for it (a char) but fscanf writes 4 bytes (unsigned int) there is an overflow.

In the case of the first line fscanf will write the bytes 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 into "box". If the "b" buffer is just after "box" on the stack then the 3 zeros will overwrite the first 3 bytes in "b" and "b" it will an empty string instead of the data you had there.

Once you changed "box" to an unsigned int it now has 4 bytes reserved for it and the overflow does not happen.

Comment: I hadn't considered that 'b' might have come after 'box' on the stack. Well spotted!

Comment: @OP so 2 problems.  OP code should have been `unsigned box;` and **the code OP posted should have matched your real code!**.  +1 for this answer, but down-voting (only my forth in 13 months) to OP's post for not posting the real code after multiple requests.